# What happened to my reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Yesterday I was around 480 and it rose into the 500. Today, it is 217? What happened?

Comment: if you search here for "recalculation" you should find plenty of discussion of what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

There's an automated process that recalculates reputation periodically.  You probably lost reputation because questions you had asked or answered were either deleted or migrated to other sites.

Comment: wow that sucks I mean it is over half my reputation

Comment: @Mike: Stop using other accounts to upvote your questions and answers.  When we delete those sock puppet accounts, you lose that reputation.

Comment: I want to go "OOO BURN" and rub it in his face, but he isn't even annotated for sockpuppetry, let alone put in the box for a week.  What gives?  Did he sock or not?

Comment: @Will: My bad, I added an annotation.  I was going to forego the suspension, since he *did* bring this to my attention himself.